# Understanding Float On Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

i'm curious about float effect on this dropdown menu http://jsfiddle.net/0eLfwoof/ .So, the thing is, if i didn't use float on nav or nav > ul , when i hover over to the sub menu , the sub menu disappear. So what i'm asking is why i have to use float here ..

```
<!--html file -->

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">list beritem</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SUB LIST</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SUB LIST2</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="">sub3 menu</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">sub3 menu</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">sub3 menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="#">SUB LIST</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

</body>

<!-- CSS -->

*{
  margin:0; padding:0;
}

p{
  color:red;
  clear:both;
}

/* it work when i make nav or nav ul float */
nav{
  float:left;
}

ul li{
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
}

a{
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:aqua;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

/*-- Second Level Menu --*/

ul li ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:110px;
  top:0px;
}

ul li:hover > ul{
  display:block;
}


li ul a{
  background-color:#298d30;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to. The problem here is that the ul is displayed as a block. When you try to hover over sublist 2, you are actually hovering over  the second list item for your first menu!  So theoretically it should work if we do this :

```
ul { 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0eLfwoof/8/

Have a look at what's happening in the DOM.

[image]

The `ul` is displayed as a block, which spans to the width of the parent (fills it completely). There are two ways which you can implement to get around this.

1. Float the element, which would not render the element as a block
2. Set display as inline-block

Don't forget that even if you set the width of an element, if an element is at block level, the margin takes up the rest of the space to fill the parent, so that won't work.

I think this should be enough to help you understand what happened.

Comment: thanks. but i use relative, so my sub nav position depends on it parent by absolute. There you say that the problem is absolute, could you please explain more why it disappear if i didn't use float? what's the connection . I'm not looking for alternative solution, just curious about it. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I realised later what your intent was when you used absolute positioning. I updated the answer to make more sense..

Comment: sweet, understood! I wonder why that happen since yesterday hehe, cause i'm not just going to accept what will work, i always curious why, so the same mistakes not comes again. Big Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It is how I learnt.. by understanding the problem. Kudos!